# Why am I unable to add an existing project to my solution in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008

I am unable to add an existing project or an existing item to any project or solution in visual studio 2008 (SP1). I only get an "Operation cannot be completed error".

Any ideas?

Things I have tried that did **not** work:

- ran devenv /resetsettings  (no luck)
- Un-installed Resharper 4.5. (no luck)
- Repaired Visual Studio from Add/Remove Programs. (no luck)
- Un-installed AnkhSVN. (no luck)

Note I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Are you able to open the existing project or item separately in vs2008?  How you tried adding the project or items to a newly created solution?

Comment: You can run devenv.exe in safemode, which might give additional hints: `devenv.exe /safemode`

Comment: Good idea, Bobby. But I'm afraid VS still fails and it does not give any extra info :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem. I am using Windows 7, so on my VS.NET EXE's properties I turned on compatibility mode for XP SP3, and I disabled Visual Themes (for VS.NET exe specifically). I also turned off clear type fonts.

Not sure which of these changes **exactly** solved the problem, but VS.NET is working again.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to blow away the .sln file, and re-create it, then add your existing projects to the new one.

I've had good success editing them by hand, so perhaps you can open it up in a text editor and take a look.

Comment: Unfortunately hand-editing the file is the only thing that has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the project and solution files are not marked as **read only**.

Comment: Good idea. But none of my files are marked as read only. So no luck there.